# parameter order for drag( ) in Raphael.js

Tags: raphael, drag

The drag method in Raphael has three parameters : **onmove, onstart , onend**.
Most examples in books show examples in that order , like this

**drag(onmove, instart, onend)**

and then declare them in any order.

Some examples show the parameters in a different order like:

**drag(onstart, onmove, onend)**

I have't been able to make it work this 2nd way but there are too many examples in books and the web for me to dismiss as just wrong. But is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The docs [here](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.drag) say...

```
Element.drag(onmove, onstart, onend, [mcontext], [scontext], [econtext])
```

And looking in the code [here](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/2.0/raphael.core.js#L2641) it supports this.

I'm not sure where you've seen the 2nd form you mention, but it looks wrong, and not sure why 'any order' for parameters would make sense. Maybe if you post a link to those examples, it may give further context. But for your own code, I would follow the docs, and then if that doesn't work, post an example jsfiddle or similar of your code for people to look at.